# Find the Sum of an Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Compute
$${1 \cdot \frac {1}{2} + 2 \cdot \frac {1}{4} + 3 \cdot \frac {1}{8} + \dots + n \cdot \frac {1}{2^n} + \dotsb.}$$

I tried creating a partition for this but no such luck.
What would the the equation to generate the sum for the nth term

Comment: A partition of what? Since $$\forall x\in(-1,1),\qquad \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0} x^n,$$ by differentiating wrt $x$ we get $$\forall x\in(-1,1),\qquad \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n\geq 1} n x^n. $$ Now evaluate both sides at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Could you please explain the symbols you used in your response? I do not understand what the most left symbol near the x signifies.

Comment: $\forall$ means "for all".

Comment: How would I calculate the factorial of 1/2

Comment: The factorial of $1/2$ is $\Gamma(3/2)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, but that has nothing to do with the present question.

Comment: I am still genuinely confused how to evaluate both sides at x=1/2- I'm not trying to fish for answers.

Comment: Just replace every $x$ with $\frac{1}{2}$ to get $$ \color{blue}{2} = \frac{1/2}{1/4} = \color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{2^n}}.$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50112/discussion-between-xarqar-and-jack-daurizio).

Comment: Check this argument: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2009676

Answer (score 3):

One may recall the standard *finite* evaluation:
$$
1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ we have
$$
1+2x+3x^2+...+nx^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
$$ multiplying by $x$ and *making* $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, *using $|x|<1$*, gives

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}. \tag3
$$ Then put $x=\dfrac12$ in $(3)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^n}=\frac{2}{2-x}$$
with a radius of convergence $R=2$

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n\frac{x^{n-1}}{2^n}=\frac{2}{(2-x)^2}$$

thus, your sum is $f'(1)=2$.

Comment: How do you solve for the radius of convergence in general for other series and sequences?

Comment: By knowing the definition of radius of convergence, I guess.

Comment: @Xarqar You have many tests: ratio, root, Hadamard, comparison, Abel lemma...

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{2^n}.$ Then 
$$2S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2n}{2^n}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(n-1)+1}{2^{n-1}} = 2+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}} = 2+S $$
hence $S=2$.

Answer (score 1):

1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ..... + 1/(2^n) + ..... = (1/2)*2 = 1

```
  1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ..... + 1/(2^n) + ..... = [1/(2^2)]*2 = 1/2

        1/8 + 1/16 + ..... + 1/(2^n) + ..... = [1/(2^3)]*2 = 1/(2^2)
```

So on and so forth.

Hence, S = 1 + 1/2 + 1/(2^2) + ..... + 1/(2^n) + ..... = 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question...

Comment: The first term 1/2 appears once. The second term 1/4 appears twice. The third term 1/8 appears thrice. So on and so forth. One can shift one term at a time and determine the sum of the corresponding series each time. Then, one sums all the sums of the series to obtain the solution.

Comment: Ah, very interesting!